# Ingore xml namespace in soap service c#

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, soap, deserialization

I am working on WCF Soap Service c#.

I want to be able to bind both these examples to my `Student` class.

Request example 1:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tem:Student>
      <tem:Name>name</tem:Name>
      <tem:Age>15</tem:Age>
    </tem:Student>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Request example 2:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <Student>
      <Name>name</Name>
      <Age>15</Age>
    </Student>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

`Student` class:

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

How do I achieve that?

What I have tried:

- I tried to intercept the request and manually remove namespace. But this solution is not suitable since the namespace "tem" could be changed. (actually it is user defined)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done by yourself?

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: It looks like the xml generated without namespaces is not meeting the schema and is wrong.

Comment: I know that. Because of that I am looking for a solution to igone the namespace